# how to add tabs to grid vales in ExtJs4

Tags: tabs, grid, extjs4

in The grid panel i have values ,when i click on the grid values it should be open in new tab in the same grid panel with related data to the grid vales

Answer (score 0):

If I am following you correctly then inside your `itemclick:function(){}` you can try this code to open a new tab

```
  Ext.getCmp('tabpanel_id').add({
        title: 'New Tab',
        layout:'fit',
        closable: true,
        items:[

           //stuff inside tab panel

        ]
    }).show();
```